# DirectSound: how to change the input volume of a microphone?

Tags: c++, volume, microphone, directsound, mixer

I have some questions about Directsound and windows mixers.
My goal is to enumerate all microphones and be able to change the input volume of each one.
I think i'm not far from the solution, but I don't find what is wrong in my code.
Here is what I have done:
- I enumerate all input devices and get a GUID for each one
- I use a method found on a topic to get the mixer id corresponding to a directsound guid using this method  (but I'm not sure if it works)
- Then I get the id corresponding to the control in the mixer
- Then I can modify the volume

Here is the code: [a vs2008 project](https://www.yousendit.com/download/TzY3eW45NEh0d0ZMWEE9PQ)

To test, I have connected two microphones usb + the line-in microphone, and I visually check what sliders are moving. But unfortunately it's not the good one ...
here is a screenshot (img177.imageshack.us/img177/5189/mixers.jpg) of all my mixers opened in windows xp.

Have you an idea of what I am doing wrong? Is there an easiest solution?

bonus question: do you know if there is a way to know if a microphone is connected or not in Line-in, using Directsound? Because the Line-in is always detected as connected even if no microphone is connected.

Comment: I think the only way to detect if a microphone is connected is to see if there is some input noise coming in.

Answer (score 0):

check this questions:

[How to adjust microphone gain from C# (needs to work on XP & W7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022981/how-to-adjust-microphone-gain-from-c-needs-to-work-on-xp-w7)

or

[http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/isvvba/thread/05dc2d35-1d45-4837-8e16-562ee919da85](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/isvvba/thread/05dc2d35-1d45-4837-8e16-562ee919da8)