# How to open Microphone properties window

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, properties, microphone

How do I open the microphone properties window when I click a button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing built in to WPF for opening the Microphone properties window. This is a .NET feature. Are you using C#?

If you want to open the Volume Control on Windows, you could just run the `sndvol32.exe` executable:

```
string lWinDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
string lSndVolPath = lWinDir + @"\system32\sndvol32.exe";
Process lVolumeControl = Process.Start(lSndVolPath);
```

See also [How to adjust microphone gain from C# (needs to work on XP & W7)…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022981/how-to-adjust-microphone-gain-from-c-needs-to-work-on-xp-w7).

Answer (score 4):

For Windows XP, starting sndvol32.exe will open the mixer. If you pass "-R" in as parameter, it will take you directly to the "Recording View", where you can set microphone gain.

```
sndvol32.exe -R
```

Unfortunately this will not work in Windows 7. Win 7 has a program called sndvol.exe but it doesn't seem to have a record settings mode. The best solution I have found is to open up the Sound control panel item with the Recording tab active using the following command:

```
control mmsys.cpl,,1
```

Comment: How do I call this command?
I try 
Process lVolumeControl = Process.Start("control mmsys.cpl,,1")
but It's not working : "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("control","mmsys.cpl,,1")`

Answer (score 0):

The right Code in C# with Windows10, and I Guess also in win7 is:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mmsys.cpl",",1");
```